# Android: colorPicker setButtonOkText not worked

Tags: android, kotlin, color-picker

I have a color picker but I need to change text
`setButtonOkText(R.string.accept)` or  `setButtonCancelText(R.string.cancel)`
but not work only color picker used default ok and cancel
and can change background pallet color? or set typeface for ok cancel texts?

```
  <resources>
    <string name="cancel">Close</string>
    <string name="accept">Accept</string>
    </resources>

        val colorPicker=ColorPickerDialog.Builder()
            .setInitialColor(Color.BLACK)
            .setColorModel(ColorModel.HSV)
            .setColorModelSwitchEnabled(true)
            .setButtonOkText(R.string.accept)
            .setButtonCancelText(R.string.cansel)
            .onColorSelected { color: Int ->

            }
            .create()
        colorPicker.show(supportFragmentManager, "color_picker")
```

[image: color picker]

Comment: Is this your `ColorPickerDialog` or a 3rd party library? If its yours can you post the code as the code you've posted doesn't say much. If its a 3rd party library then can you link the git or source?

Comment: implementation 'io.github.vadiole:colorpicker:1.0.2'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update 2022

This bug was fixed in version 1.0.3, so now you just need to update the dependency

```
implementation 'io.github.vadiole:colorpicker:1.0.3'
```

### Old answer

Unfortunately the library looks like it has a bug.

The positive and negative buttons never have their text set to the passed in ids.

https://github.com/vadiole/colorpicker/blob/master/colorpicker/src/main/java/vadiole/colorpicker/ColorPickerView.kt

Look at lines 201 and 202 this is the only time these 2 buttons are pulled and neither of them call `setText`. The xml shows they are hardcoded to default strings.

Luckily there may be a workaround in here,

https://github.com/vadiole/colorpicker/blob/master/colorpicker/src/main/java/vadiole/colorpicker/ColorPickerDialog.kt

You will need to override two classes `ColorPickerView` and `ColorPickerDialog`

`ColorPickerView` will only need you to provide a modified constructor. Call it `FixedColorPickerView`

```
constructor(
    context: Context,
    actionOkRes: Int,
    actionCancelRes: Int,
    @ColorInt initialColor: Int = Color.DKGRAY,
    colorModel: ColorModel,
    colorModelSwitchEnabled: Boolean,
    onSwitchColorModelListener: OnSwitchColorModelListener? = null,
) : super(context,
          actionOkRes,
          actionCancelRes,
          initialColor,
          colorModel,
          colorModelSwitchEnabled,
          onSwitchColorModelListener) {
            //Your constructor will simply grab the buttons and set their texts 
            //after the real constructor has inited view.
            val positiveButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.positive_button)
            val negativeButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.negative_button)
            positiveButton.setText(actionOkRes)
            negativeButton.setText(actionCancelRes)
}
```

`ColorPickerDialog` you need to override 2 methods

`onCreateDialog` to replace the`ColorPickerView` its creating.

`onSaveInstanceState` to avoid a `NPE` due to the reference to the old  `ColorPickerView`

```
class FixedColorPickerDialog : ColorPickerDialog {
    var fixPickerView: ColorPickerView by Delegates.notNull()

    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        val bundle = savedInstanceState ?: arguments!!
        val actionOk = bundle.getInt(ACTION_OK_KEY)
        val actionCancel = bundle.getInt(ACTION_CANCEL_KEY)

        fixPickerView =
            FixedColorPickerView(
                requireContext(),
                actionOk,
                actionCancel,
                bundle.getInt(INITIAL_COLOR_KEY),
                ColorModel.fromName(bundle.getString(COLOR_MODEL_NAME_KEY)),
                bundle.getBoolean(COLOR_MODEL_SWITCH_KEY),
                onSwitchColorModelListener
            )

        fixPickerView.enableButtonBar(
            object : ColorPickerView.ButtonBarListener {
                override fun onNegativeButtonClick() = dismiss()
                override fun onPositiveButtonClick(color: Int) {
                    onSelectColorListener?.onColorSelected(color)
                    dismiss()
                }
            }
        )

        return AlertDialog.Builder(requireContext()).setView(fixPickerView).create()
    }
    override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
        val bundle =
            makeArgs(
                fixPickerView.actionOkRes,
                fixPickerView.actionCancelRes,
                fixPickerView.currentColor,
                fixPickerView.colorModel,
                fixPickerView.colorModelSwitchEnabled
            )
        outState.putAll(bundle)
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

##### Hello, I'm the developer of this library.

This bug was fixed in version 1.0.3, so now you just need to bump the version:

```
implementation 'io.github.vadiole:colorpicker:1.0.3'
```

Thank you for your feedback. Feel free to create new issues in the [GitHub repo of the library](https://github.com/vadiole/colorpicker).